# Write bytes to file from Huffman encoding algorithm

Tags: haskell, byte, bit

I'm learning Haskell and as first challenge I chose to write an implementation of Huffman coding, the algorithm is almost done, only the part of read and write the file to a byte file is missing.
What I need to do is a way to write a file based on the binary string I build.

For example, If a read from a `txt` file the following string `Hello`, after the huffman algorithm, I get the following Map which map the symbol to his binary number as string

```
[
  ("H": "110"),
  ("e": "111"),
  ("l": "0"),
  ("o": "10")
]
```

And I need to replace that bytes in the readed string and write as Bytes that binary numbers to a file, I tried to use the ByteString package and the writeFile function, but the function write the binary numbers as plain text and not as Bytes.

So that way `Hello` pass to be `110111010` that should be write as Bytes to a file.

Comment: Take a look at `hPut`: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.10.0/docs/Data-ByteString.html#v:hPut

Comment: You can only pass bits in multiples of eight, you can padd it with zero, or use characters (so `'1'` instead of a bit `1`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a string of `'0'`s and `'1'`s to a file with [**`writeFile :: FilePath -> String -> IO ()`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/System-IO.html#v:writeFile). For example:

```
main :: IO ()
main = writeFile "out.txt" "110111010"
```

You can also convert eight bits to a `Word8` and then write the `ByteString` to a file with the [**`WriteFile :: FilePath -> ByteString -> IO ()`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.10.0/docs/Data-ByteString.html#v:writeFile) of the [**`Data.ByteString`** module](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring/docs/Data-ByteString.html):

```
import Data.ByteString(writeFile, pack)
import Data.Word(Word8)

writeWord8s :: [Word8] -> IO ()
writeWord8s = writeFile "out.txt" . pack
```

You can convert a list of `Bool`s to `Word8`s, but then this has to be a multiple of eight. You can for example "pad" it with `0`s (or `1`s, or something else), but it should be a multiple of eight:

```
import Data.Bool(bool)
import Data.Bits((.|.), shiftL)
import Data.Word(Word8)

toWord8 :: [Bool] -> Word8
toWord8 = foldl ((. bool 0 1) . (.|.) . (`shiftL` 1)) 0

pack8pad0 :: [Bool] -> [Word8]
pack8pad0 [] = []
pack8pad0 xs
    | null ys = [toWord8 (y ++ replicate (8 - length y) False)]
    | otherwise = toWord8 y : pack8pad0 ys
    where (y, ys) = splitAt 8 xs
```

I leave mapping the input to a `String` of `'0'`s and `'1'`s as an exercise.